# Division of two numbers in freemarker - incorrect result

Tags: syntax, configuration, freemarker

I'm using freemarker 2.3.26 with Kotlin. I have two variables in my template and I need to divide them.

```
Variable ${a} is Int and its value is 28.
Variable ${b} is Int and its value is 5.
Output of ${a/b} should be 5, but really it is 6.
```

I've found out that this is probably caused by rounding

```
28/5 = 5.6 = rounds to 6
```

How to correctly handle this? Is there any other - more elegant - way than this?

```
${(a/b)?floor}
```

Comment: Why it isn't elegant?

Comment: It is quite long, especially when the variable names are longer. And it adds unnecessary noise into template code. I understand why result is 6, but it is little bit confusing and I'd expect it to be 5 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `number_format` configuration setting must be something like `'0'`, hence the decimals are lost *when the number is converter to string*. I would never use such a `number_format`, because it's confusing and all. With a usual `number_format` like `'0.####'`, you get `5.6`, because 5 / 6 is indeed 5.6, and if you need to floor it, then you need to be explicit about it. Now, if you are sure you want to drop the decimals during formatting (but again, I think it's a dangerous practice), then use a `number_format` like `'0;;roundingMode=floor'` (since FreeMarker 2.3.24), and then `${28/5}` will print `5`.

Another, probably better solution is that if both numbers are of integer Java types, then you do integer division (like Java). That's possible by setting the `arithmetic_engine` configuration setting to `conservative`. That's again not a good practice in general, because the template language doesn't declare the type of the variables, so it's not obvious what `a/b` will do. As the data-model evolves, and you switch from `BigDecimal` to an integer Java type, that can lead to wrong output.

Comment: Thanks. I'm working on bigger project and I've found out, that our number_format was set to "#". Using [documentation](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_setting.html), I was able to change it locally like this: `<#setting number_format="0.####">`, but there seems to be no way to changing it back :(

Comment: Currently there's no feature to restore the earlier `number_format`, if that's what you mean. Of course, if you could call `<#setting number_format="#">`, but it's obviously not a very maintainable approach. However, I'm not sure if anyone at the project wants that `"#"` default... it's maybe just a mistake, and should be reported to the responsible team.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I had in mind :) I've found one workaround - set the default format to some template variable and then do `<#setting number_format=ourDefaultFormat>`. That works and is probably more maintainable, yet not ideal. I will also discuss that default setting in our team - maybe I will not need any workaround then :)

Comment: @AlešZrak What you are saying as a workaround is not a solution for *restoring* the number format though. But then maybe that's not what you want, and these two features can be interesting for you (see the FreeMarker Manual for details): 1. With the `template_configurations` setting the `number_format` (and most other settings) can depend on the path/name of the main (top-level) template.  2. `custom_mumber_formats` setting lets you register named formats globally, like you register `physical` as an alias to `0.####`, and then write `<#setting number_format='@physical'>`.